# Command Line customization

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, terminal, bashrc

I was looking a video on how to install Kubernettes on Ubuntu, the guy on the video has this really cool way on displaying his command line in a terminal. I was wondering if someone could help me to pinpoint the right wording to do a google search and try this for myself?. I asume he is doing his thing over Ubuntu, is this particular to Gnome Shell? could it be achieved on another Linux Flavors?

[image: I would love to have a Command Line like the one on the pic]

PD. this is the location of the video I am talking about.
https://www.ubuntu.com/containers/kubernetes

Cheers and thanks for sharing your knowledge.
EN

Comment: Nice, indeed. You should include `command prompt` in your search and `PS1` environment variable. Doing the background colors is not too hard, and this seems to be done with some graphical Unicode chars.

Comment: It is called powerline: there are tutorials all over the web for how to set it up.

Comment: There are many alternatives. Take a look at [powerline](https://gist.github.com/ricardobeat/5980892) or a [pure bash prompt](https://github.com/riobard/bash-powerline). Here is [a guide to install](http://www.tecmint.com/powerline-adds-powerful-statuslines-and-prompts-to-vim-and-bash/) and an [interesting github prompt line](https://github.com/arialdomartini/oh-my-git)

Answer (score 1):

There are many alternatives.
You may take a look at [powerline](https://gist.github.com/ricardobeat/5980892) or a [pure bash prompt](https://github.com/riobard/bash-powerline).
Here is a [guide to install](http://www.tecmint.com/powerline-adds-powerful-statuslines-and-prompts-to-vim-and-bash/) and an [interesting github prompt line](https://github.com/arialdomartini/oh-my-git).

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the "agnoster theme" from [oh my zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/themes)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your comments. I finally found it, it is a port of powerline, that is called powerline-shell.

please follow the link to the git repository and to instructions on how to install and implement in your shell.

https://github.com/banga/powerline-shell